# Get view count for magento product based on product_id

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to display a view count on a category listing page in Magento.  This data looks like it used to be accessible via reports/product_collection but I can't find a way to access it correctly.

I'd basically like to supply a product id and get the view count of the said product returned to me.

Comment: I came across this thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/27684/ ?

Comment: This worked, but like stated in the thread it was pretty slow.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the view count through the `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` model.

```
// set $to and $from to an empty string to disable time range filtering
$from = '2012-01-01';
$to = now();
$productIds = array(9, 35); // your product ids, (works as an int, too) 

$reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $productIds);
```

Each item in the collection is a `catalog/product` instance with a views property set, so you can use `$product->getViews()` to get the count.

If you don't want to load the whole product model and only require the view count, you can get it like this:

```
$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/event');
$select = $resource->getReadConnection()->select()
    ->from(array('ev' => $resource->getMainTable()), array(
        'product_id' => 'object_id',
        'view_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')
    ))
    // join for the event type id of catalog_product_view
    ->join(
        array('et' => $resource->getTable('reports/event_type')),
        "ev.event_type_id=et.event_type_id AND et.event_name='catalog_product_view'",
        ''
    )
    ->group('ev.object_id')

    // add required filters
    ->where('ev.object_id IN(?)', productIds)
    ->where('ev.logged_at >= ?', $from)
    ->where('ev.logged_at <= ?', $to);

$result = $resource->getReadConnection()->fetchPairs($select);
```

This gives you an array, the keys are the product ids and the values are the view counts.

Comment: What is the diff using `SELECT COUNT(*) AS views FROM report_viewed_product_index WHERE product_id=446` ?

Comment: Also what are the object_id and subject_id means here in report_event tables?