# How to sort by most viewed in Magento?

Tags: magento, sorting, categories, product

In Magento 1.7 i am trying sort product by most viewed product but not successfully done
I am trying to edit toolbar.php file in magento core file please give best solution for sorting product by most viewed

check it on - http://www.bindaaslo.com/mobile-tablets/mobile-phones.html

```
class Sugarcode_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
```

Comment: Did any answer help to solve your problem? What's still the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Havent done it myself but I think you will need to retrieve the view count by product ID and then sort it accordingly.
Have a look at [Get view count for magento product based on product_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172755/get-view-count-for-magento-product-based-on-product-id) might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the most viewed products with following code (it worked for me):

```
<?php                               
    $productCount = 5; // Top 5 products
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();                             

    $_mostViewed = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->setPageSize($productCount);                               

    foreach ($_mostViewed as $product){
        echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br>';  // Example code
    }
?>
```